# JNI Virtual machine taking 4GiB of virtual memory just by launching it

Tags: c++, linux, jvm, java-native-interface

We have observed that in our Linux machines (Red Hat), C++ processes instantiating JVMs using JNI (we have a bunch of the kind) are taking ~4GiB of VSZ according to a `ps`, JUST BY LAUNCHING THE PROCESS (we don't need to instantiate a single object or use any library to reproduce the problem).

Minimial code to reproduce the problem:

```
// C++
#include <jni.h>
#include "unistd.h" // sleep

int main()
{
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args = {};
    JNIEnv* env_ = 0;
    JavaVM* jvm_ = 0;

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm_, (void**)&env_, &vm_args);
    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}

# Makefile
JAVA_HOME = /etc/alternatives/java_sdk
CPPFLAGS = -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include
LDFLAGS = -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm

all: test

test: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Execute `./test`, wait between two or three seconds, and then:

```
$  ps -Ao"pid,time,vsize,rssize,pcpu,args" | grep -E "PID|test" | grep -v grep
    PID     TIME    VSZ   RSS %CPU COMMAND
 372587 00:00:00 4078292 25304 1.2 ./test
```

4GB of VSZ. You can increase the sleep amount as much as you can, it won't change the result, so it's not an initialization singularity. Of course, I'm worried about those 4GB. If we keep our real processes running long enough we start having issues with the heap space of the JVM.

In AIX, however:

```
$ ps -Ao"pid,time,vsize,rssize,pcpu,args" | grep -E "PID|test" | grep -v grep
     PID        TIME   VSZ   RSS  %CPU COMMAND
37552202    00:00:00  8544  8548   0.0 ./test
```

8MB.

What could be happening?

The Java version (in both AIX and Linux) is 8.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

Read Hat versioning info:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.3 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.3"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.3:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.3"
```

Comment: Why do you care about virtual memory usage? It's virtual for a reason. As long as the memory is not actually _used_ both your application and kernel can pretend it is there. RSS (actual memory in use) is the thing to worry about.

Comment: @Botje because the virtual size doesn't grow that much unless someone request it. My suspicion is that the virtual machine thinks it's ok for him to have a memory pool of 4GB. We have observed the JVM growing up to 2GB of resident size after some days of usage and the JVM start complaining about heap usage problems. We haven't seen this problem in AIX, although we are still researching it.

Comment: Yes, this is why you use JVM options to restrict the size of the JVM heap (and various other memory pools).

Comment: this is more a [tag:jvm]¹ question, than a [tag:java]  one! || **¹** "*Use this tag for questions dealing with tools provided by a JVM or how it works in a specific scenario. || **²**"* Use this tag when you're having problems using or understanding the language itself.*"

Comment: @Botje how can I know the current settings of the JVM? I know how to specify options, but I don't know how to check what the current values are.

Comment: See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-jvm-heap-size) for a good introduction on the heap options and how to find what your JVM sets as default.

Comment: Off: What's the point in creating a Java application in C++?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond because we need a Java library not available for C++.